# How do overloaded methods work

Tags: c#, .net

I've been programming for may years first Delphi and now c# so I thought I knew how overloaded method worked, but apparently not.

First some code

```
public enum TestEnum { Option1, Option2, Option3 }

public class Setting
{
    public Setting()
    {
        AddSettings();
    }

    protected void CreateSetting<TEnum>(string AName, TEnum AValue) where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    protected void CreateSetting(string AName, string AValue)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    protected void CreateSetting(string AName, int AValue)
    {
        CreateSetting(AName, AValue.ToString());
    }

    protected void AddSettings()
    {
        CreateSetting("Language", (byte)0); //#1
        CreateSetting("BFL", "true"); //#2
        CreateSetting<TestEnum>("TestEnum", TestEnum.Option1); //#3
        CreateSetting("TestEnum", TestEnum.Option1); //#4
    }
}
```

I've added a number to each call to CreateSettings in order for making it easyer to explain.

My question as :

**Call #1** calls the wrong (Generic) version of CreateSettings because I've made a cast to a `byte` but why?

**Call #2** works just fine.

**Call #3** works just fine as well. I explicit calls the gerneric version

**Call #4** also works but with some "magic" the compiler resolves the correct (genneric) version and calls that. But why does it work?

I have figured out that #1 call the wrong version for the same reason that #4 works. I was just wondering if any one could give me an explanation.

Comment: Preceisely which version of the .Net framework/Visual studio are you using for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The overloads are working as expected, you stated that:

*#1 calls the wrong version*

It calls the **correct** version because what you're doing is casting the `int` to a `byte`, so you no longer have an `int` variable, you have a `byte`. Are you expecting it to match the `int` overload? How could it, you've just cast the variable to a `byte`.

*Call #4 also works but with some "magic"*

This isn't magic, this works basically because of the same reason as the above, the type is neither an `int` or a `string`, so the only other possible overload it could call is the generic one because your "generic" method essentially says any other class (the type here is `TestEnum`)

Comment: Call #1 calls the generic overload as there is a conversion between enum and byte

Comment: ok by "wong" I meant diffrent than I expected. ans yes I expected it to hit the int version because I wasn't aware the #4 was a valid syntax. I got the idea for thath one when #1 called the "wrong" version.

Comment: @VMAtm It calls the generic overload because it's neither a `string` nor an `int`

Comment: Just to "deffend"  my self the code is from a class and I added the generic overload to it. And then it stopped working. I did ofcause quickly find the error but that just lead to my question.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt No worries, it's a valid question :). If you try sending a decimal value to your function, you'll see it goes to the generic one too, just to make it clearer :)

Comment: :) I just wasn't aware that the syntax of #4 was valid and there fore I was expection the compiler to call the int overload.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt #4 is using type inference, i.e. it allows you to omit the type and the compiler can still work out what you meant because of your parameter types. If there's any ambiguity (for example, if it could match more than one overload), you'll still get a compiler error. More here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The method called is determined by the process of **overload resolution**.

The compiler builds a list of possible candidate methods that could be called based on the types of the parameters passed, and then ranks them based on a set of rules that determine which method is the best option to call based on the quality of any type conversion that may occur. You can view these rules here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691339%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

The general overload resolution process is described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

By following through these rules and comparing to each of your scenarios you should be able to see which rule you are hitting in each case.

Answer (score 1):

**Call #1**

You made a constraint where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable

Which means the type TEnum is either a value type or a type that implements the two interfaces 
you have a byte argument which means the method that will be called is method 1 since byte is a value type and none of the other methods accepts byte as an argument

**Call 2** and **Call3**

Works as expected

**Call4**

Again the compiler would resolve to the first method because Enum is a value type and none of the other method accepts the Enum type as an argument so the most appropriate overload is method 1

Comment: Your explanation for call #1 is not correct, since constraints are not part of the signature. See this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx. Call #1 calls the generic method since it is the only candidate left (byte is not an int or string).

Comment: Thats what I meant , it sees all the possibilities and since byte is a value type it will go with the first method, if it was class instead of struct it would give you a compile time error